# find relatives in-common or not-in-common based on multiple people?

Tags: dna, ancestry.com, 23andme

Out of the hundreds of DNA relatives that show up I only recognize a few. My paternal grandfather's side is a complete mystery; I haven't found one person I recognize from what I know of my family tree.  I only know my maternal family back to my grandparents so I think many of the unknown 3rd and 4th cousins it my list of total matches could be on my maternal side.

What I'd like to do is select known cousins from the three non-paternal-grandfather branches and then list people that are not-in-common with any of them. Presumably most or all of these would be related to my paternal grandfather.

I looked on 23andme & ancesty.com which have an in-common-with filter but I first need to select a match and then the filtering is only done with regard to me and the one match.

Is there a way to select multiple relatives and then get a list of my matches that are not-in-common with all of us?

Answer (score 1):

I checked FamilyTreeDNA, MyHeritage, and GEDmatch, and they also do not do what you're looking for (but you might want to upload your DNA to those sites for additional matches, if you haven't already). Potentially, [Genome Mate Pro](https://www.getgmp.com/) might do this, but I don't know the software well enough to say for sure.

It could be done with tables in Excel with a little bit of work, or with a script (VBA macro or other language).